# getting the previous and next value from a dataframe and add a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am new to python and pandas. Here I have a dataframe which is like ,

```
 Id     Offset       feature
   0        0              2
   0        5              2
   0        11             0
   0        21             22
   0        28             22
   1        32              0
   1        38             21
   1       42             21
   1        52             21
   1        55              0
   1        58              0
   1        62              1
   1        66              1
   1        70              1
   2        73              0
   2        78              1
   2        79              1
```

Now In this df, I have a feature column. I am trying to do some operations on this column. This column has some values. It also has a `0` value in it. Now, I want to replace this value on the basis of previous and next three values of this 0.

If we see,first 0 which has previous values are [2,2] as it is a first so it will not get the third one and the next three are [22,22,0] .

Now I am trying to get the following dataframe

**Expected output**

```
Offset       feature       previous        Next            NewFeature 
 0              2             -             -                 2
 5              2             -             -                 2
 11             0           [2,2]          [22,22,0]          0
 21             22             -            -                 22
 28             22            -             -                 22
 32              0          [22,22,0]      [21,21,21]          0
 38             21            -              -                21 
 42             21            -              -                21
 52             21            -              -                21 
 55              0           [21,21,21]     [0,1,1]            0
 58              0           [0,21,21]      [1,1,1]            0   
 62              1             -              -                1
 66              1             -              -                1
 70              1             -              -                1
 73              0           [1,1,1]         [1,1]             1 
 78              1             -               -               1
 79              1             -               -               1
```

So, In this I am trying to checking that if previous and next are same or not.

Is there any way I can get this dataframe ? How do I get the previous and next values in this dataframe ? any help will be great .
Thanks

So, The logic for getting the `newFeature` is that .
Here I have the features list which is ,

```
1, 2, 16,15,26,25
if the previous and next array has values like, (1,16,15) then it is the same as 1. and if it is from (2,26,25) then we can replace it with the 2.
```

Here if the

```
previous values are [1,16,2] and next are [1,26,1]  then in this as I said earlier (1,16,15) are 1 only .. so the number of 1 are more than 2 so, the 0 will get replaced by 1. and 26 will become 2
```

like it will become [1,1,2]  and  [1,2,1]

So, this way. even the given data also we can use .

Comment: What is logic for new column `NewFeature` ?

Comment: So, the logic I will just update in the question it self.

Comment: I am confused with `1, 2, 16,15,26,25`, because I cannot find this numbers in sample data.

Comment: actually sorry.. I have added these values which are not in the sample data. Sorry for that.. should I update the sample data ?

Comment: Is possible update lists by data in question?

Comment: I will just update some data like that.. and also the conditions in it as well.

Comment: Hey, we can even use the given dataframe as well .. we can consider these values instead of the others. I have also added some lines where I have explained the condition. could you please check .

Comment: Actually One thing I forgot to add is the document Id . currently it is happening it on the random basis. In the df  I have one more column.I will just add that

Comment: ok, so if forget for some column, better is edit data.

Comment: Yes I have just added that, Actually,it is on the basis of the document Id, otherwise it will take take the previous value from the previous document ID if there is a 0 on the last

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201832/discussion-between-jezrael-and-ganesh-kaspate).

Answer (score 0):

This should get you in the right direction:

```
import pandas as pd
# create a dummy df
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['feature'] = range(100)
df = df.sample(frac=1)
# create shifted columns
df['shift1'] = df['feature'].shift()
df['shift2'] = df['feature'].shift(2)
# concat the previous values
values = df.loc[:, ['shift1', 'shift2']].values
df['prev'] = values.tolist()
# you just want the zeros, right?
df.query('feature == 0')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
x = df['feature'].tolist()
y = x[::-1]
df['previous'] = [y[-i:][:3] for i in range(1, len(x)+1)]
df['Next'] = [x[i: i + 3] for i in range(1, len(x) + 1)]

df['previous'] = df['previous'].shift(1).where(df['feature'] == 0, '-')
df['Next'] = df['Next'].where(df['feature'] == 0, '-')
print (df)
    Offset  feature      previous          Next
0        0        2             -             -
1        5        2             -             -
2       11        0        [2, 2]   [22, 22, 0]
3       21       22             -             -
4       28       22             -             -
5       32        0   [22, 22, 0]  [21, 21, 21]
6       38       21             -             -
7       42       21             -             -
8       52       21             -             -
9       55        0  [21, 21, 21]     [0, 1, 1]
10      58        0   [0, 21, 21]     [1, 1, 1]
11      62        1             -             -
12      66        1             -             -
13      70        1             -             -
14      73        0     [1, 1, 1]        [1, 1]
15      78        1             -             -
16      79        1             -             -
```

Comment: Hey but here Y is undefined . It is not defined there,

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - oops, I remove it -, need `y = x[::-1]`

Comment: Here , whats happening is all data is scattered. It should be on the basis of document ID.

Comment: is there any way so that the data will not be in a scattered way ?

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - I was busy, now I edite answer. Give me some time.